# Private keys work for putty but not pscp

Tags: ssh, putty, pscp

I am using a Windows machine which is using private/public keys to connect to a Debian server. I have placed the public key in my user account at ~/.ssh/authorized_keys . I can log in successfully with Putty. However, when I try to use pscp.exe it does not work.

The command I am using is this:

```
h:\pscp -P portnum -i h:\path\to\my.privatekey.ppk *.tgz username@ipaddress:
```

Where portnum, username, and ipaddress are filled in with my server's information.

The above command generates the following error:

```
Fatal: expected key exchange group packet from server
```

What is this error saying? Why can I use the private key with putty but not with pscp? I have set up other servers and connected with pscp just fine.

**Update**

Using the verbose option I get the following info:

```
Server version: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4p1 Debian-10+deb9u3
Using SSH protocol version 2
We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Snapshot_2010_02_04:r8855
Doing Diffie-Hellman group exchange
expected key exchange group packet from server
Fatal: expected key exchange group packet from server
```

Comment: Are you using the newest version of putty?

Comment: @mariaczi wow, that was the issue! I was using `pscp: Development snapshot 2010-02-04:r8855` . I now downloaded version 0.70 and it works. However, what has changed? Why does the old one work with my other servers, but not this particular server?

Comment: I think that's due to the changes done in OpenSSH's DH key-exchange implementation a few years ago... 8 years is a lot of time for bugs to appear or disappear.

Comment: Why did my question get downvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your pscp.exe binary file. You are using very old:

```
We claim version: SSH-2.0-PuTTY_Snapshot_2010_02_04:r8855
```